# lie bracket and double extension

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

Hi if someone can  help me please.

Let $(A,\langle,\rangle$)  be a flat pseudo-Riemannian Lie algebra which contains an ideal $ I $ of
totally isotropic dimension 1 such that $I^{\perp}$  is also a two-sided ideal. Let $I=\mathbb{R} e$ and let $ \bar{e} \in A $ defined by $ \langle e, \bar{e} \rangle = 1 $ and $ \langle \bar {e}, \bar {e} \rangle = 0. $ Let $\hat{B}=\operatorname{vect}\{e, \bar{e}\}^{\perp}$.
Then $ A $ identifies as a vector space with $\mathbb{R} e \oplus \hat{B} \oplus \mathbb{R} \bar{e}$ and $ I^{\perp} $ to  $\mathbb{R} e \oplus \hat{B}$

Q: Using the bracket on $A$ expresses, for $a, b \in B $, by
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
{[\bar{e}, e]=\mu e} \\
{[\bar{e}, a]=D(a)-\left\langle b_{0}, a\right\rangle e} \\
{[a, b]=[a, b]_{B}+\left\langle\left(\xi-\xi^{*}\right)(a), b\right\rangle e}
\end{array}\right.
$$

where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}, D \in \operatorname{End}(B)$ and $b_ {0} \in B $. According to the formula
$$
\langle x . y, z\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\{\langle[x, y], z\rangle-\langle[y, z], x\rangle+\langle[z, x], y\rangle\}
$$

Q: I didn't understand how can I find the following equation?

$\bar{e} . a=-\left\langle b_{0}, a\right\rangle e+\frac{1}{2}\left((D-\xi)(a)-\left(D^{*}-\xi^{*}\right)(a)\right)$

$\bar{e} \cdot e=\mu e$